# Exchangeable Random Variables Confusion

Tags: probability

A sequence of random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is said to be exchangeable if any permutation of the sequence has the same joint distribution.  I thought I understood what this meant, but I was confused by the following example which I've quoted from Wikipedia:

> Suppose an urn contains $n$ red and $m$ blue marbles. Suppose marbles are drawn without replacement until the urn is empty. Let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable of the event that the $i$th marble drawn is red. Then $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is an exchangeable sequence. *This sequence cannot be extended to any longer exchangeable sequence.*

I believe that this is an exchangeable sequence, but I don't understand this last sentence.  For example, it seems to me that $X_1,\ldots,X_n,X_{n+1}$ should be exchangeable.  Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a typographical error. The full sequence $(X_1,\ldots,X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots,X_{n+m})$ looks exchangeable to me. For this sequence you can calculate
$$E(X_1) = \frac n{n+m}\tag1$$
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_1)=\frac{nm}{(n+m)^2}\tag2$$
and if $i\ne j$,
$$
E(X_iX_j) = \frac{n(n-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}
\tag3$$
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=-\frac{mn}{(n+m)^2(n+m-1)}=-\frac1{n+m-1}\operatorname{Var}(X_1).\tag4$$
Note that (4) achieves the lower bound on $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ for a sequence of $n+m$ exchangeable random variables. This means the full sequence cannot be extended; if it were possible to extend to $n+m+1$ variables while preserving the joint distribution for the first $n+m$, we would require the new sequence to satisfy the lower bound for $n+m+1$ exchangeable variables:
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\ge -\frac1{n+m}\operatorname{Var}(X_1),$$
which is violated by (4).

Comment: How exactly could one even extend to $n+m+1$ variables?  There's only $n+m$ trials that we're considering, so I don't know how one would interpret $X_{n+m+1}$.

Comment: @Sam The last variable could be anything, it wouldn't have to be the indicator of the $n+m+1$ draw. Any r.v. taking value in $\{0,1\}$ *could* be a candidate.

Comment: @Sam Right, the conclusion is that no vector of $n+m+1$ random variables exists that can extend the given $n+m$ variables without compromising exchangeability. So the given sequence is 'maximally' exchangeable (and note every subcollection of these $n+m$ variables is also exchangeable).